# How to use Hide and show queries within IF conditions J QUery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, show-hide

So lets say my question is that i have a drop-down with 2 value like values1 and value2, when I click value1, then field 1 should show up, and when i choose value2, field 2 shows up like this

```
function acc_type() {
  if (jq('#dropdownID').val() === "") {
    jq('#field1').hide();
    jq('#field2').hide();
  }
  jq('#dropdownID').on('change', function() {
    let acct_type = jq('#dropdownID option:selected').text();
    if (acct_type == "value1") {
      jq('#field1').show();
      jq('#field2').hide();
    } else if (acct_type == "value2") {
      jq('#field1').hide();
      jq('#field2').show();
    }
  });
}
```

and my task is when certain field shows up, make them mandatory, there's existing function call with an Error which i need to add but how do i make it work.. my try was something like this below

```
if (jq('#field1').show() && !jq('#field2').val()) {
  addErr(`A value for <a href="javascript:void(0)" onlick="jq('#field2').focus()">Field 2</a> is required.<br>`);
} else if (jq('#field2').show() && !jq('#field1').val()) {
  addErr(`A value for <a href="javascript:void(0)" onlick="jq('#field1').focus()">field 1</a> is required.`);
}
```

first part of code is working fine, "addERR()" is also fine, but i can't think of any way to  do my part like when 1 is hidden and other is showing with empty field, it should throw out error.
Please see fast enough if  anyone can help. This is my first question on Stack.

Comment: If you wrap everything in a `<form>` and add `required` on the `<input>` or whatever (your question doesn't have any HTML (which is why I'm not answering)) then it'll have a popup message when `<form>` is submitted (submission is stopped of course).

Comment: `.show()` says "make this visible" rather than "is this visible" and always returns a jquery -object/collection (even if empty) so will always be truthy - to check if an element is visible you need `if ($(#field1").is(":visible")...`

Comment: @freedomn-m,  yeah you're right, that's what i was missing. I like never tried "is this visible" thing so that's why i was stuck on this one. nevertheless Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Update here,

Found solution myself

```
if (jq('#field1').is(":visible") && !jq('#field2').val()) {
  addErr(`A value for <a href="javascript:void(0)" onlick="jq('#field2').focus()">Field 2</a> is required.<br>`);
} else if (jq('#field2').is(":visible") && !jq('#field1').val()) {
  addErr(`A value for <a href="javascript:void(0)" onlick="jq('#field1').focus()">field 1</a> is required.`);
}
```

The thing I was doing wrong instead of `show()` I needed to use

```
is(":visible")
//or hidden instead of visible
```